# How To Fix Errors With Simulink Support Package

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am practically a complete beginner to MATLAB, Simulink, and Raspberry Pi so please bear with me if I seem dumb.

For some reason, whenever I try to set up the Simulink support package so that I can program my Raspi, I encounter one of two errors.

Either Simulink does not detect the Raspberry Pi Board or I recieve an error:

Warning: Unable to load block diagram 'embdlinuxlib'

and my blocks are red and empty.

How can I fix this issue? I can connect to the Pi fine in the regular Matlab but for some reason simulink does not work.

Thank you in advance.

[image: This is the block error.]
[image: This is currently working, but if the blocks load then Raspi would not be in this list.]